# Surface pro 3 weaker processing while plugged in

Tags: windows-10, cpu, power-management, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I am encountering a strange issue in that my Surface Pro 3 seems to run more slowly (more lag in games) when plugged in, and I was wondering if anyone on here might have experienced a similar issue, or have any idea what's going on.

My only thought was that the power settings were limiting the CPU, but I checked the registry (because they don't appear in power settings anymore) and the limits are 0 and 100 whether plugged in or not. Keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\893dee8e-2bef-41e0-89c6-b55d0929964c

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\893dee8e-2bef-41e0-89c6-b55d0929964d
```

Comment: Limits are 0 and 100, is this minimum and maximum?

Comment: I believe so, as percentage. All I'm trying to say is that I don't believe the power settings are causing the issue.